# Excel pivot table: move value fields from row to column

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table

I'm developing an excel addin in c# and have to create a pivot table, which I don't know how to organize the data, how it should be.

First of all the datasource:

[image: Pivot Data Source]

This is, how the final Pivot Table should looks like:

[image: Pivot should looks like this]

But I only get something like this and I have no Idea where I have to how to change my code:

[image: This is what my code does with it -.-]

Finally my code to arrange the data source columns:

```
/* PIVOT RowFields */
Excel.PivotField nameField = pTable.PivotFields("Name");
nameField.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
nameField.Position = 1;

Excel.PivotField monthField = pTable.PivotFields("Monat");
monthField.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
monthField.Position = 2;

/* PIVOT Data */
Excel.PivotField sum200Field = pTable.PivotFields("Summe 1");
sum200Field.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField;

Excel.PivotField sum700Field = pTable.PivotFields("Summe 2");
sum700Field.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField;

Excel.PivotField sumDiffField = pTable.PivotFields("Differenz");
sumDiffField.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField;
```

I'm using .NET Framework 4 ... I read a lot of articles in the internet, but nothing I read was useful...

Does anyone have an Idea?

UPDATE:

As @MP24 posted, adding these two C#-Lines at the end of my code, the columns will be display right exclusive the grouping of name and month:

```
Excel.PivotField dataField = pTable.DataPivotField;
dataField.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField;
```

UPDATE2:

To group Month and Name Column, the following code will show how to:

```
/* PIVOT ZEILEN */
Excel.PivotField monthField = pTable.PivotFields("Monat");
monthField.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
monthField.LayoutCompactRow = true;
monthField.LayoutForm = Excel.XlLayoutFormType.xlOutline;
monthField.set_Subtotals(1, false);

Excel.PivotField nameField = pTable.PivotFields("Name");
nameField.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
nameField.LayoutCompactRow = true;
nameField.set_Subtotals(2, false);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to change the orientation of your data fields:

The VBA code is

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").DataPivotField.Orientation = xlColumnField
```

This translates into C# code:

```
Excel.PivotField dataField = pTable.DataPivotField;
dataField.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField;
```

**Edit:** Note that for understanding the pivot tables, the macro recorder will give you good hints. Just start recording the macro just before you perform your desired action, and stop the macro afterwards. Transferring the insights from the code into C# will then be easy.

Comment: Thank you very much. I used the macro recorder, but that gives me just the hints i already used, but your C#-Code works very well for displaying the data right ... There is just one more thing: How can I "group" Name & Month? These both fields are displayed in seperate columns.

Comment: I got it with the grouping, I will add it to my original post =)

Comment: This line worked for me at the end of the table build:

pTable.DataPivotField.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField;

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
pivotTable.DataOnRows = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```vb
PivotField fld = pivotTable.RowFields("Data");
fld.Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField;
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.